# Not receiving IPv6 RA packets

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, ipv6

I have a new Dell XPS13 Sputnik edition that came with 14.04 installed and it's not picking up an IPv6 address by auto configuration.

Network manager is set to Method: Automatic

Running wireshark I can see the outbound RS packets being sent and on both this machine and a different machine (Fedora 22) running radvdump I can see the response RA packet is being broadcast by the router but I see nothing on the Dell.

I've tried running `rdisk6 -1 wlan0` to force a new RS packet to be send but I still get nothing back.

I've checked the content of /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0 and everything looks sensible.

- accept_ra = 2
- autoconf = 1
- disable_ipv6 = 0
- forwarding = 0

No firewall setup at the moment

Any ideas?

OK, this gets a little stranger, I've just plugged a USB Ethernet adapter in and I get RA packets just fine, so it looks like it's something to do with the wifi.

Comment: Did you check to see if there is anything blocking the packets in `ip6tables`?

Comment: No, ip6tables totally clear